# Calculating GRID Statstics

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, statistics

I have a GRID raster dataset with no calculated statistics. I have tried building pyramids and calculating statistics with no luck. What am I missing?

EDIT:
For those who don't understand:
1. ArcToolbox-->Data Management
2. Raster-->Build Pyramids and Statistics

I have also tried to build pyramids and calculate statistics separately, from the same toolbox.

SOURCE:
http://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/globalmarine/impacts

Comment: edited, though I don't see how it adds any information to the questions. thought I was pretty clear.

Comment: GRID format should have the statistics built already, if not it could be *broken*. Have you moved it in explorer? Is it more than 4 directories down from the drive? Have you changed its name? How did you get it and what have you done to it???

Comment: Error message? What is happening when you try to run the stats? Are you launching from ArcMap or ArcCatalog.

Comment: No error message. From a reputable University source. I have tried through ArcCatalog and ArcMap. The professor warns that statistics will need to be built for these datasets after Arc 10.0.

Direct message on website: If you're an ArcGIS 10 user, you'll need to 
 build pyramids to see these datasets, or zoom in to the dataset scale: ESRI changed the format for Pyramids, and these files use the older format. After recreating the pyramids, the datasets should display as expected.

Comment: Just a thought, GRID is an antiquated but still valid format that has some **serious limitations** consider converting to ERDAS Imagine format either with copy raster or GDAL_Translate -of HFA; use the adf file as the input. Then you can build pyramids and statistics on the img.

Comment: Yep, I would convert to IMG as well and then just build.  If you export to grid in another location I suspect this will work as well.

Comment: IMG works, @MichaelMiles-Stimson, post your answer so I can mark it please!

Thank you VERY much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GRID format, although valid and still working, it antiquated and has some serious limits:

GRID data is in a folder which sits in a 'workspace' which is made from a folder with an *info* directory which keeps tabs on the GRID, INFO and Coverage data contained therein. Because of this you can't just rename the GRID or move the GRID unless you move the whole workspace. Note: GDAL doesn't seem to care so much and will still read the GRID even if it's been moved away from its INFO directory or renamed.

GRID has a limitation on the length of its name, 13 characters, which is because the `arc.dir` in the info folder keeps track of names and only allows 13 characters in the column.

The drivers that read GRID data don't like spaces or non-alphanumeric characters in the path, also it only buffers to a certain length and number of folders. I'm not 100% sure on these limits but it's best to keep GRID data less than 10 folders deep and less than 128 characters in the full path.

The INFO directory has a limit of 10000 files, each GRID has two files in the INFO directory with that and the `arc.dir` the count must be less than 10000.

There may be more limits but that's all I can remember.

If possible convert to ERDAS Imagine format either with [CopyRaster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000094000000) or using GDAL_Translate:

```
GDAL_Translate -of HFA c:\path\to\grid\hdr.adf C:\path\to\output.img
```

Substitute your own paths of course. To use GDAL on Esri GRID format supply the hdr.adf file that is inside the GRID.

Now calculate statistics and build pyramids as normal.

Comment: What serious limits are you referring to?

Comment: GRID rasters can't be copied in explorer, they can't be renamed in explorer, their names must be less than 13 characters, they must be less than 10 deep in the folder structure, path names can't contain invalid characters, you can only have just over 4000 in the same workspace... Few users understand how gentle you need to be with GRID data and run into problems, best to make it an img or tif.

Comment: It's just a personal opinion but I think your answer would be improved by including those limits rather than a sweeping generalisation.

Comment: Yes, possibly @Luke. I could list some of the limitations if you think that would help but to be fair I'd have to go searching for where they are and provide the links and I'm not sure how many of them would be available. I can remember working in ArcINFO workstation with GRID data and most of what I know came from ArcDoc which, to my knowledge, isn't online. I will put a few in there if I can find links.